# if else problem...why the console didnt print string 'error' but it printed 'Randommm' instead?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Nice to meet you all. I am new to programming here....my question is why the console didnt print string 'error' but it printed 'Randommm' instead? since it did not pass the first statement

```
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
      userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
      if (userInput === "rock" || "scissors" || "paper" || "bomb") {
        return userInput;
      } else {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    };
    
    getUserChoice("Randommm"); //output:'nothing comes out instead of 'Error'

console.log(getUserChoice('rocK')) //output :rock (works fine)
```

Comment: because of your if statement, you cant compare the way you have done. Try `(userInput === "rock" || userInput === "scissors" ||userInput ===  "paper" || userInput === "bomb")`

Comment: Instead of use it i suggest to use array with `includes` like `if(["rock","scissors","paper","bomb"].includes(userInput))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement isn't making a comparison in the 2nd,3rd and 4th conditions. You have to explicitly state what to compare against. You could do something like:

`(userInput === "rock" || userInput === "scissors" ||userInput ===  "paper" || userInput === "bomb")`

But i suggest you lift the words out to an array and do a comparison if the userinput exists within the array.

```js
const choices = ["rock", "scissors", "paper", "bomb"];

const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (choices.includes(userInput)) {
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log("Error");
  }
};

console.log(getUserChoice("Randommm")); //output:'Error' instead of 'Randommm'
```

Comment: Except your code outputs 'Error' and not 'Randommm' like the comment says.

Comment: The expected output is Error. 'Randommm' if I understood it correct, was the userInput returning because of the conditions being met despite input being wrong. @JeremyThille Thanks for the snippet by the way, I need to remember doing them

Comment: So the comment on the last line should be the other way around

Comment: True, I copied the code from the author. Edited now.

Comment: done. thanks alot as it is my first question in stackoverflow as i didnt find the answer somewhere. it definitely helped me in my programming journey

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding because just now realized i made some mistake and edited it after you posted the explanation. sorry for the inconvinence caused